# memory trace of all variables in program with DBI tool

Tags: memory, memory-profiling, intel-pin

I am using intel pin as my primary DBI tool.
I am interested to know how can I trace all variables allocated in a program .

suppose, we have the following snippet in C:

```
int *ptr_one, *ptr_two, g;
ptr_one = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
ptr_two = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
*ptr_one = 25;
*ptr_two = 24;
g = 130;
free(ptr_two);
g = 210;
*ptr_two = 50;
```

I want to know how can I trace specific variables / memory references in my program . for example on the above code, I like to trace the variable "g" in my program with Intel Pin, how it can be done?

for dynamically allocated variables, I'm monitoring malloc/free calls  & follow their addresses, but for static ones I do not have any idea .

Another matter is, for dynamically allocated variables, I like to trace them across the whole program, suppose in the above code, I want to monitor (ptr_two) variable changes and modification during my program from start to finish .

If anyone have some idea about that, it can be nice to share it here, sample codes appreciated in Intel Pin .

thank you all .

Answer (score 0):

Simply stated, you can't associate a name from your source code (be it variable or function name) with a memory location on the compiled binary: this information is (probably) lost on the final binary.

This is not true in two cases:

1) If your binary is exporting functions: in this case other binaries must have a means to call the function by name (minus some subtleties), in which case the information must be available somewhere; for example on Windows, binaries that export functions, variables or classes have an export table.

2) You have symbolic information: in your example, either for the global variable or other local variable, you have to use the symbolic information provided by the compiler.

On Linux you will need an external tool / library / program (e.g. libelf.so or libdwarf.so) to parse the symbolic information from the symbol tables (usually dynsym / symtab) **if the binary is not stripped**.

On windows you have to rely on the program database (*.pdb files); the format is mostly undocumented (although MS is [trying to document it](https://github.com/Microsoft/microsoft-pdb)) and you have to use either the [DbgHelp API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679291(v=vs.85).aspx)  or the [DIA SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x93ctkx8.aspx).

As stated by the [PIN user guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/81205/Pin/html/index.html#SYMBOLS) (emphasis is mine):

> Pin provides access to function names using the symbol object (SYM).
>   Symbol objects only provide information about the function symbols in
>   the application. **Information about other types of symbols (e.g. data
>   symbols), must be obtained independently by the tool**.

If you have symbolic information you can then associate a variable name - obtained from an external tool - with an address (relative to the module base for global vars or a stack location for local ones). At runtime it is then just a matter of converting the relative address to a virtual one.